# WSO2 splitter giving exception

Tags: exception, wso2, threadpool, axis, splitter

I am having a request splitter in WSO2 ESB, but if i send 4-5 messages i am able to get proper response.

if the request is having lets say around 10-15 messages i am getting unhandled exception saying.

```
2014-09-09 13:02:50,548 Uncaught exception  More
```

TID[-1234] [ESB] [2014-09-09 13:02:50,548] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} - Uncaught exception org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296) org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78) org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722) org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:719) org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:719) org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.cloneOMElement(OMElementImpl.java:1034) org.wso2.carbon.tracer.module.handler.TracingMessageInObservationHandler.invoke(TracingMessageInObservationHandler.java:33) org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340) org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313) org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261) org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183) org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

any help how to configure Axis Server to have more threads in pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases like Iterator, you can increase thread pool size in synapse.properties (can be found under ESB_HOME/repository/conf/), there you can adjust following properties for better performance

synapse.threads.core = 20 
synapse.threads.max = 100

also check if the incoming payload is correct

Comment: increased the thread count, will it required the heap tuning as well ?